# Why do I need to add method to a Java interface, to access it in a Junit unit test?

Tags: java, interface

I'm mainly a C#, .NET developer and am used to interfaces and TDD in C#. Interfaces in C# primarily define the contract when implemented. The usage seems to be slightly different in Java. In particular, it seems that every project I've come across implements a basic interface for accessing the application, as if it's *always* a requirement for any Java app to utilise an interface. I'm thinking I'm missing some basic understanding, so I'd really appreciate any prompts to a good primer that I can read.

For example, I have a test which looks like this (in a separate 'Test' folder in my solution):

**Tests.java**

```
package com.dius.bowling;

class DiusBowlingGameTest {

    private BowlingGame bowlingGame;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        this.bowlingGame = new DiusBowlingGame();
        this.bowlingGame.startGame();
    }
```

To be able to access `this.bowlingGame.startGame();` I need to add the method to the interface. Why? There seems to be a difference between Java and C#/.NET I'm unaware of?

**Interface**

```
package com.dius.bowling;

/**
 * Interface for a bowling game.
 */
public interface BowlingGame {
    /**
     * roll method specifying how many pins have been knocked down
     * @param noOfPins no. of pins knocked down
     */
    void roll(int noOfPins);

    /**
     * get player's current score
     * @return player's current score
     */
    int score();

    void startGame();
}
```

**DiusBowlingGame**

```
package com.dius.bowling;

/**
 * Scoring system for tenpin bowls
 */
public class DiusBowlingGame implements BowlingGame {

    ArrayList<BowlingFrame> gameFrames = new ArrayList<BowlingFrame>();

    public void roll (int noOfPins) {

       /* Implementation */
    }

    }

    /**
     * Activate the 1st frame of the game
     */
    public void startGame() {
        advanceFrame();
    };
```

Comment: _"as well as enabling cleaner multiple inheritance"_ there is no multiple inheritance in C#. Neither in Java. You can implement multiple interfaces, but that's not the same as "multiple inheritance".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, interfaces work the same in C# and Java. The only differences are that it is common to name interfaces with an "I" in the beginning at C# and that in C# both classes and interaces use the `:` operator, whereas in Java the keyword `implements` is used for interface, the keyword `extends` is used for classes. Your code does not need the interface, it would work perfectly also this way:

```
package com.dius.bowling;

class DiusBowlingGameTest {

private DiusBowlingGame bowlingGame;

@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    this.bowlingGame = new DiusBowlingGame();
    this.bowlingGame.startGame();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If it's not in the interface, and you store the reference in a variable of the interface type, how does the compiler know the method exists?

In general, the value assigned to the variable could be any implementation of `BowlingGame`. Unless the method is on the interface, there is no requirement for those classes to implement the method.

To avoid adding the method to the interface, either change the variable type to `DiusBowlingGame`, or use a local variable in the `setUp` method:

```
DiusBowlingGame bowlingGame = new DiusBowlingGame();
bowlingGame.startGame();
this.bowlingGame = bowlingGame;
```

Comment: _" could be any subclass of BowlingGame"_ *any _implementation_, since it is an interface. (Maybe I am nitpicky, but well ...)

Comment: I also fail to see how the interface behaviour seen in Java is any different to C# (or any other language with interfaces)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it should be `bowlingGame.startGame();` without the `this.` reference because you want to refer to the local variable.

Comment: @Dirk yep, typo.

Comment: Doh! Good spot @Andy Turner. I was overthinking it.